# module import in Python

Tags: python, import, module

If I have a module say 
A.py, wherein

```
import xxx
import yyy

class P:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
p = P()
```

Will the last line of code be executed every time I import A, in every module, or just once?
I am attempting to make it a singleton instance, i.e. to be able to use only one instance throughout the session of execution. So please share, how that can be done.
Thanks.

Comment: every time you import A (for the first time) in every module. Just add a `print` to convince yourself :)

Comment: __for the first time in a same proces__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code at a module's top level is only executed once per process (the first time the module is imported for this process). The `module` object instance is then stored in `sys.modules` and subsequent imports will access it from there.

The only caveat is when the same module is imported via 2 different qualified names, in which case it's treated as two distinct modules (hence the top-level is executed twice for the same process), but that's really a quite uncommon corner case.

Here's a simple example where you can see that in actions - `mod.py` is imported four time but executed only once (on the first import):

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ ls *.py
a.py  b.py  c.py  main.py  mod.py

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ cat mod.py
class P(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "p %s initialzed" % id(self)

p = P()

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ cat a.py
print "in a.py"
import mod

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ cat b.py
print "in b.py"
import mod

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ cat c.py
print "in c.py"
import mod 

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ cat main.py
import a
import b
import c
import mod

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/imptrace$ python main.py
in a.py
p 139818712152976 initialzed
in b.py
in c.py
```

Edit: You state that

> I am attempting to make it a singleton instance,

This won't make your class a singleton - nothing prevents someone to create other `P` instances. If you really want a singleton, you'll have to either override `P.__new__()` to prevent more than on single instance to be created (canonical singleton) or change `P` so that it only uses class attributes and classmethods, so that all instances will actually share the same attributes.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @bruno desthuilliers

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol glad I could help - and feel free to accept the answer then ;)

Comment: Sure. will do that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes - you are indeed correct.
Every time you import this class, an object of type `P` will be created.
Everything outside the class/function definition is effectively seen as an executable command

Comment: Wrong. A module's top-level is only executed once (on the first import) for a given process.

Comment: Apologies, I did not take multiple imports into account.